# Understanding the proof of $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem

Tags: measure-theory

Dynkin's $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem states that if $\mathcal{P}\subset\mathcal{L}$ and $\mathcal{P}$ is a $\pi$-system and $\mathcal{L}$ is a $\lambda$-system, then $\sigma(\mathcal{P})\subset\mathcal{L}$. I found a proof of the theorem here: [https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~rdhough/mat639-spring17/lectures/lecture1.pdf](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/%7Erdhough/mat639-spring17/lectures/lecture1.pdf)

[image]

"Let $\mathcal{l}(\mathcal{P})$ be the smallest $\lambda$-system containing $\mathcal{P}$..." How do we know that the "smallest" $\lambda$-system containing $\mathcal{P}$ actually exist? If it exists then by the rest of the proof we get $\sigma(\mathcal{P})\subset\mathcal{l}(\mathcal{P})\subset\mathcal{L}$. But how do we know that it indeed exists?

Comment: Take all $\lambda-$ systems containing $\mathcal P$ and take their intersection.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thanks